# Find a conserved quantity of a dynamical system to reduce the dimension of this system

Tags: dynamical-systems, physics, mathematical-physics

Let $x_{1} , x_{2}, x$ points which are forced to move on a line, the mass of $x$ is M and the mass of $x_{1} , x_{2}$ is m with $M>m$. The points $x_{1} , x_{2}$ are connected to $x$ via two ideal springs with elastic constant $k>0$. Gravity is not to be considered.

The Lagrangian of the system is $\mathcal L = \frac{1}{2}(m( \dot x_{1}^2 + \dot x_{2}^2) + M\dot x^2) - \frac{1}{2}k((x-x_{1})^2 + (x-x_{2})^2)$

Turns out, total momentum is a conserved quantity independent from the Energy.

My question is how could I reduce the degree of the system?

I tried to replace the momentum inside the energy equation but I cannot delete one of the variables from the potential term.

Comment: Did you use coordinates $y\equiv (x_1+x_2)/\sqrt{2}$ and $z\equiv (x_1-x_2)/\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: Do you see that the energy of the the *z* d.o.f. is *separately* conserved, as a decoupled oscillator's?

Comment: ........Do you         ?